# Can Maybe be used for optional arguments?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm having trouble getting the following to work in GHCi. It's a short example that pops up several places online.

```
import Data.Maybe

elseZero :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> a
elseZero n = fromMaybe 0 n
```

My understanding is that when I load this into GHCi and then run with `elseZero` it should return 0, since no argument is given.

But I receive the error:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that `it' has the inferred type
  it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (Maybe a)) => a
```

New to all parts Monadic of Haskell. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question stems from a misunderstanding of [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) and a confusion about `elseZero`'s type signature: `elseZero` is a function that requires one argument (`Maybe a`). GHCi will complain if you try to evaluate it without supply it a value of type `Maybe a`. `elseZero Nothing` returns `0`, because no value can be extracted from `Nothing`.

Comment: `Maybe a` is not an optional argument, you have to provide a value of type `Maybe a` e.g. `fromMaybe Nothing` or `fromMaybe (Just 3)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs. Looking at the types for the Just (a -> Maybe a) and Nothing data constructors was very helpful. I was hoping to use Maybe as a way of cleaning up some code by making optional function parameters take default values. I now see that this will either require using Just or a helper function.

Comment: @todkwxrtvwmzonunswam You may like Brent Yorgey's post on [incremental ad-hoc parameter abstraction](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/haskell-anti-pattern-incremental-ad-hoc-parameter-abstraction/).

Answer (score 2):

`elseZero`'s type is `(Num a) => Maybe a -> a`, so that is what GHCi will try to `show` you. However, functions are not `show`able, which is what the error message is telling you.

Your fundamental misunderstanding seems to be that you think `elseZero` and `elseZero Nothing` are the same. But the former is a function of type `(Num a) => Maybe a -> a` that returns either the `Just`-value or 0, and the latter is 0 of type `(Num a) => a`.